# I have an API response which should come before anything else loads up or renders in the browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, fetch-api

I have an API response which  should come before anything else loads up or renders in the browser but it gives response which is slower than the loading of first component which rendered on the page.
This the code for the API call which i make to get the data is given below. Is there any way I can make this given below to be executed synchronously?

```
const GetLanguageData =   (pageName) => {
const traslationApiUrlObj = {
languageCode: $('#hdnLanguageCode').val(),
baseUrl: `${apiUrl}`,
page: pageName
}
const { baseUrl, languageCode, page } = traslationApiUrlObj;
const traslationApiUrl = `${baseUrl}${languageCode}/${page}`;
ResourceLanguageText = null;
fetch(traslationApiUrl)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((result) => {
        ResourceLanguageText = result;
        console.log('Result');
    },
        (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

Comment: You have a react tag in the question so I will assume its react. You will need to have a flag like `isLoading` so while the request is not done it will be `true` and your component will just return null. Once its `false` and you have the data your component returns the actual markup.

Comment: actually i am using a js file,i might have added the react tag by mistake.This is actually a javascript file

Answer (score 0):

it can be achieved using combination of state and componentdidmount() lifecycle method.

keep a boolean flag in state "loaded" initialized to true.

call api in componentdidmount(), after you receive response set "loaded" to true in state.

in your render() method, do a conditional render based on your loaded is true